# Objective-C POST Request not correctly "posting"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, post

I'm trying to develop an app for school, and the first step is to `POST` into our grade book. My code is as follows:

```
NSString *usernameText = _username.text;
NSString *passwordText = _password.text;
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",usernameText, passwordText];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"(school website, not putting real URL)"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

The issue is that, it doesn't "work". The webview refreshed, but no data is inputted nor is the page changed. I'm wondering what I did wrong, and if I might have overlooked something. Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
I've tried the NSURLSession and got this in my response:
(censored website name, gives location away)

```
2018-12-13 20:07:07.277108-0500 sisParsing[29432:2736415] Error: (null)
2018-12-13 20:07:07.277459-0500 sisParsing[29432:2736415] Response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6000028ce300> { URL: website } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" =     (
    "*"
);
"Cache-Control" =     (
    "no-cache, no-store"
);
"Content-Length" =     (
    13437
);
"Content-Type" =     (
    "text/html; charset=utf-8"
);
Date =     (
    "Fri, 14 Dec 2018 01:07:29 GMT"
);
Expires =     (
    "-1"
);
Pragma =     (
    "no-cache"
);
Server =     (
    "Microsoft-IIS/8.5"
);
"Set-Cookie" =     (
    "ASP.NET_SessionId=hchdpifc13c3hhrowxnjjzfj; path=/; secure; HttpOnly"
);
"X-AspNet-Version" =     (
    "4.0.30319"
);
"X-Powered-By" =     (
    "ASP.NET"
);
} }
```

Comment: Perhaps _webview is nil. Did you connect it in xib file?

Comment: No, it can load basic URL requests and I just doubled check. It's connected.

Comment: I think its a bug in WKWebView since 2015: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18952. I think the only solution is to use a UIWebView or WebView. Although it is deprecated.

Comment: That's weird - is there any way to do it without a WebView at all? Also, a week ago this code was working perfectly, and I've changed nothing

Answer (score 0):

When working with POST or GET data to web backend, it is always great to install Postman app (ITS FREE AND EASY TO USE). Try to send a request from Postman with the same data (username and password) and see what the web backend replies. This way, you will know for sure whether it's your code or the backend that has a problem. I am not affiliated with Postman but I am currently developing web app also, and it is the best tool to help me debug the code.

Alternatively, you can also try sending the POST request without using webview, by using NSURLSession and see what reply you got back or what error your app produces. Something like below:

```
//before this you need to construct session object with appropriate url and params. (google to see example).

NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
 NSLog("Error: %@", error);
 NSLog("Response: %@", reponse);
}];

[postDataTask resume];
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hey thanks! Check my edit, I'm newish to HTTP requests and don't know what to make of it.

Comment: NSError is null, and response code is 200 that means your request is successful. So you can now try to decode the data received. If the format is json, you can try adding `NSDictionary *json  = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
                                                    NSLog(@"%@",json);` in the nsurlsession block.

Comment: I added it and got `(null)` as the response.

Comment: Wait a minute. Might be your web app does not return a json. In that case, you can try just print out NSLog("%@", data); or maybe convert data to NSString first then NSLogging that.

Comment: I converted the `NSData` to an `NSString` and it gave me the source code of the website

Comment: So after some further research, I downloaded Firefox's Developer version and opened the developer tool that records POST and GETs. I logged in to the site, and saw that the POST sent was a 302 error which means page moved (I think). I downloaded `Postman` and set the params to what the browser said and resulted in an error. I tried a different website, and sure enough it worked. What do I do from here?

Comment: You need to check the web back end. If you own it, then you need to debug there. Otherwise you need to contact the web developer. Perhaps he modified some url calls or something.